# How get into a running docker container and run a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, containers

I am trying to run a python script in a running docker container in detached mode like so:

```
docker exec -d pylot python3 pylot.py
```

I have tried this, but this fails silently. How can I run this python script with docker exec?

Comment: Try run the command without `-d` first. You try to get into a running docker container with `detached` mode?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the container you are using?